# Python building function to generate all possible alignment between two sequence?

Tags: python

I'm working on IBM1 model for language process. It uses EM algorithm. However, based on the pseudo code provided, I need to find all possible alignment given two sentences. For example: `A = [a,b], B = [c,d]`. I need to given `[(a->c, b->d),(a->d, b->c)]`. (here `a->c`  means a aligns with c) It's easy when the sentence has only two words. but In general, when there are many words. What is the fastest way of python to generate all alignment?

This is particularly hard because: it's not simply pairwise alignment.

for example:  `A = "the blue house". B = "le mansion bleu".`

the possible alignment :

`"the->le, blue->mansion, house->bleu"` could be one such alignment

`"the->mansion, blue->le, house->bleu"` is another one

and so on

Comment: Isn't it just a permutation?

Comment: The fastest way is to write a piece of code quickly to solve your problem.  You should make an effort on your own to solve your issue before posting.

Comment: @chrisz depending on OP's background knowledge (in combinatorics, recursion, Python, etc.), it may be extremely difficult or even impossible to even get started on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import permutations

A = "the blue house".split()
B = "le mansion bleu".split()

for perm in permutations(B):
    print(list(zip(A, perm)))
```

Output:

```
[('the', 'le'), ('blue', 'mansion'), ('house', 'bleu')]
[('the', 'le'), ('blue', 'bleu'), ('house', 'mansion')]
[('the', 'mansion'), ('blue', 'le'), ('house', 'bleu')]
[('the', 'mansion'), ('blue', 'bleu'), ('house', 'le')]
[('the', 'bleu'), ('blue', 'le'), ('house', 'mansion')]
[('the', 'bleu'), ('blue', 'mansion'), ('house', 'le')]
```